# If $N$ is a nontrivial normal subgroup of a nilpotent group $G$, then $N\cap C(G)\neq \langle e\rangle$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

This is an exercise from a book of algebra.

> If $N$ is a nontrivial normal subgroup of a nilpotent group $G$, then $N\cap C(G)\neq \langle e\rangle$.

This is my proof:

If $N\cap C(G) = \langle e\rangle$, then $C(N)\cap C(G)= \langle e\rangle$,then $g\in C(G)$ doesn't commute with any element $n\in N$ which is a contradiction since $N\subset G$.

My question is if the condition $N$ normal is trivial,and is my prove right?

Comment: The condition $N$ is normal is important , and could you explain why the second implication holds ? To give you hint, prove the result for p groups (p prime), if N is a non trivial normal subgroup of a p group G, then $N \cap C(G) \not =\lbrace 1 \rbrace$.

Comment: I realized my second implication can not holds, and thanks for your useful hint.@mich95

Comment: @mich95 I think your hint is only relevant to finite groups and there is no finiteness asumption here.

Comment: @DerekHolt,  Thanks for that! I just learnt that there are infinite "nilpotent " groups.

Comment: Should it be right away obvious that a finite nilpotent group is the produt of its sylow subgroups ?

Comment: A fintie group is nilpotent iff it is the direct product of its Sylow subgroups.@mich95

Comment: @mich95 A general group is defined to be nilpotent if it has a (finite) central series. The result that finite group is nilpotent if and only if it is the direct product of its Sylow subgroups is not obvious. One approach is to prove nilpotent $\Rightarrow$ all proper subgroups properly contained in their normalizers $\Rightarrow$ all maximal subgroups normal $\Rightarrow$ all Sylow subgroups normal $\Rightarrow$ direct product of Sylow subgroups $\Rightarrow$ nilpotent.

Comment: And you are using the fact that normalizers of sylow subgroups are "self" normalizing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the upper central series of $G$, $Z^0(G)=1\leqslant Z(G)\leqslant \cdots \leqslant Z^c(G)=G$, for some $c$. There is a least $k$ such that $H\cap Z^k(G)\neq 1$. Normality gives $[H\cap K,G]\leqslant H\cap [K,G]$. Use this and $[Z^k(G),G]\leqslant Z^{k-1}(G)$ to conclude.

Comment: Can the lower central series work as well?

Answer (score 0):

Lemma: Observe that $Z_{k}/Z_{k-1}=Z\left(G/Z_{k-1}\right)$ and $H$ normal in $G$ imply
\begin{align*}
    \left(H\cap Z_{k}\right)/\left(H\cap Z_{k-1}\right)
    &\leq Z\left(G/\left(H\cap Z_{k-1}\right)\right)
\end{align*}

Proof of Lemma:
Consider $g_{1},g_{2}\in H\cap Z_{k}$ so $g_{1}g_{2}g_{1}^{-1}g_{2}^{-1}$ is in both $Z_{k-1}$ and $H$. That is, $g_{1}g_{2}g_{1}^{-1}g_{2}^{-1}\in H\cap Z_{k-1}$. Thus the lemma.

Proof:
Suppose $H\cap Z_{k}$ is non-trivial and $H\cap Z_{k-1}=1$. Then the lemma implies $H\cap Z_{k}\leq Z\left(G\right)$. On the other hand, if $H\cap Z_{k-1}$ is non-trivial, the process continues. Thus the result.